# need to change the class of (parent) upon selecting radio button. jquery

Tags: jquery

**my html code**

```
<td valign="top" class="padtop10 appgreyunselect">
    <input name="raddate" type="radio" value="trans-date" class="resmarpad rad" /> Transaction Date
</td>
<td valign="top" class="padtop10 appgreyunselect">
    <input name="raddate" type="radio" value="collect-date" class="resmarpad rad" /> Collection Date
</td>
```

**my js code**

```
$("#myForm input").click(function(){
    if($('input[name=raddate]:checked')){
       $(this).parent().removeClass('appgreyunselect').addClass('fontwht11');
    } else {
       $(this).parent().removeClass('fontwht11').addClass('appgreyunselect');
    }
});
```

Actually the code written is doing the perfect thing, but this is not I wanted,
   if un selecting then the label would turn back to previous class(appgreyunselect). But they remain white color. 
Pls help...

Comment: Replace `.click` to `.change`. Also, add you css too, or even better, create a snippet or bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On change of radio button remove `fontwht11` class and add `appgreyunselect` to `.padtop10`. If radio button is checked then remove `appgreyunselect` class and add `fontwht11` to the parent like following.

```
$("#myForm input").change(function () {
    $('.padtop10').removeClass('fontwht11').addClass('appgreyunselect');

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('appgreyunselect').addClass('fontwht11');
    } 
});
```